# Alterar um valor de texto através de ponteiro em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, tipagem, printf

Preciso alterar os valores das variáveis através de seus ponteiros mas não estou conseguindo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Programa principal
int main()
{//Declaração de variáveis e ponteiros
    int x = 0; int*p;
    float y = 0; float *l;  
    char z = 'B' ; char *m;

    //Apontamento de ponteiros
    p = &x;
    l = &y;
    m = &z;
    //Impressão dos valores antes da modificação
    printf("O valor de x antes da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y antes da modificao eh : %f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z antes da modificao eh : %\n", z);

    //Inserindo valores que os ponteiros devem alocar na memória das variáveis
    *p = 70;
    *l = 63.70;
    *m =  'A' ; //ERRO - Não consigo fazer a inserção do valor deste ponteiro em sua variável

    //Impressão dos valores após a modificação
    printf("O valor de x depois da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y depois da modificao eh : %.2f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z depois da modificao eh : % \n", z);

    //Fim do programa
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Notem que consigo alterar os valores das variáveis como `int` e `float`, mas do tipo `char` retorna sem nenhum conteúdo e não sei mais como proceder.

Comment: Ali não dá erro, o que tem de errado é outra coisa, não está formatando corretamente: https://ideone.com/XB3bOl

Comment: Ele mostra o "B"?

Comment: Pra mim deu um warning na compilação na linha do printf, parace ter faltado um %c.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Ajudou muito, dúvida sanada.

Answer (score 2):

Não há erro na atribuição, ela está correto, como as outras, o erro está na formatação da impressão de caracteres. O [`printf()` espera o `"%c"`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) para imprimir um dado do tipo `char` ou outro compatível que queira imprimir como texto. Em ambos faltam. Aproveitei e melhorei algumas coisas e simplifiquei o código, tem muita coisa desnecessária.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0; int *p = &x;
    float y = 0; float *l = &y;  
    char z = 'B'; char *m = &z;
    printf("O valor de x antes da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y antes da modificao eh : %.2f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z antes da modificao eh : %c\n", z);
    *p = 70;
    *l = 63.70;
    *m = 'A';
    printf("O valor de x depois da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y depois da modificao eh : %.2f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z depois da modificao eh : %c\n", z);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XB3bOl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lrmhfdzx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintfChar.c).

Aproveito para dizer que embora seja um exercício interessante, o uso de ponteiro nessa forma é desincentivado porque ele não tem propósito.

Comment: Maniero entendi o que estava faltando. valeu pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Faltou no seu último `printf` que exibe a mensagem: `O valor de z antes da modificao eh` o `%c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Programa principal
int main()
{//Declaração de variáveis e ponteiros
    int x = 0; int*p;
    float y = 0; float *l;  
    char z = 'B' ; char *m;

    //Apontamento de ponteiros
    p = &x;
    l = &y;
    m = &z;
    //Impressão dos valores antes da modificação
    printf("O valor de x antes da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y antes da modificao eh : %f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z antes da modificao eh : %c\n", z); //Faltou o %c aqui 

    //Inserindo valores que os ponteiros devem alocar na memória das variáveis
    *p = 70;
    *l = 63.70;
    *m =  'A' ; //ERRO - Não consigo fazer a inserção do valor deste ponteiro em sua variável

    //Impressão dos valores após a modificação
    printf("O valor de x depois da modificao eh : %d\n", x);
    printf("O valor de y depois da modificao eh : %.2f\n", y);
    printf("O valor de z depois da modificao eh : %c\n", z); //Faltou o %c aqui 

    //Fim do programa
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda man .... esta funcionando